# How get bold and normalfont item into theorem?

Tags: theorems, enumitem

I have a numbered list into theorem. Example

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries\normalfont{\roman*.}}]
 \item 
\end{enumerate}
```

But the picture below show the item is with normalfont but non-bold text. I want bold text for item. How can I get that?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\normalfont` sets `\mdseries`. Use `\normalfont\bfseries\roman*.`. Note that these switches do not take arguments.

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={\roman*.}, font=\normalfont\bfseries]
 \item 
\end{enumerate}
```